# Applying a design to a subset of buttons in Android

Tags: android, button, material-design

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    app:strokeColor="@color/black"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/button_clear"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:text="C"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_sign"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button_sign" />
```

I am building a calculator app so I wanted my number buttons to have a different background color than my operation buttons and my equal button to have a different background.

What is the most effective way to apply this to a group of buttons?

I am new to Android Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a default style:

```
<style name="CalculatorButton" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="strokeColor">@color/....</item>
        <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

Then you can define others which inherit from the default. Something like:

```
<style name="CalculatorButton.Number">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
</style>

<style name="CalculatorButton.Equal">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

Then in your `Button` just refer the right style:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/CalculatorButton.Number"
    ..>
```